# MVC5 - Most Efficient Way to Access the User Object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

While learning C# and MVC, I'm using the stock MVC template in VS2013 Preview,  I'm trying to get a reference to the User class (what the templates creates in the IdentityModel.cs file) of both the currently logged in user (if applicable) or from a user id guid.

Currently I have this (and it works), but it seems a little convoluted and possibly expensive (I'm not sure how it all works under the hook).

```
IUser iUser = await Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());  //have to reference Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to access the GetUserId method
IUser iUserFromId = await Users.Find("user id guid placeholder");

User user = iUser != null ? (User)iUser : null;
```

Is there a cleaner or more efficient way of doing this?  Is there away do it without async methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new identity api is intended to be async so you are doing it correctly.

You could write it in one line as:

```
User user = await Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()) as User;
```

In RTM it will change a little bit, but the gist of it is the same except the Manager will be have a generic so you don't have to do the cast and will look more like:

```
User user = await Users.FindAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())
```

Comment: What does RTM stand for?